# Cydia app version are identical in update and app itself, but Cydia asking for update

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I've made an app in Theos and uploaded it on my own repo. The version of app is 1.0.5-3 and I added string `Version: 1.0.5-3` in `Packages.gz` file in the repo. But Cydia ask me to update this app every time. Versions are identical on the iPhone and on the repo, but Cydia don't understand it. Why is that happiening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found where the problem was. The other things in `Packages` file was different with strings in `control` file inside .deb, so everything must match.

Comment: This problem can be avoided by using some sort of automated process.  Generally, the Packages file should be generated, for example, by running a script like `dpkg-scanpackages`. This will keep your Packages and Control files in sync.